# Why is $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty, \mathbb{Z})$ not $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-k-theory

This is some confusion about standard facts.

The cohomology ring of $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ is a polynomial ring in one variable.  However, it is also well-known that for generalized cohomology theories, if the inverse system $h^t(X^n)$ satisfies the Mittag-Leffler condition, we have
$$ h^*(\varinjlim X^n) \cong \varprojlim h^*(X^n) $$
If we think of infinite projective space as the colimit of $\mathbb{CP}^n$, can we then conclude:
$$ H^*(\mathbb{CP}^\infty; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \varprojlim H^*(\mathbb{CP}^n; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \varprojlim \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^{n+1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[x]] $$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your argument is fine. Since $\deg x =2 $, the graded rings $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ coincide. (Technically, the issue here is that the cohomology graded ring is really a series of abelian groups $H^p(X)$ and nice maps $H^p(X) \otimes H^q(X) \to H^{p+q}(X)$. To make this object into an ordinary ring, we can take either $\bigoplus H^*(X)$ or $\prod H^*(X)$. In finite dimensions, they coincide; here, we really want the latter for exactly the reason you describe.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your last point?  Where does the infinite sum $\sum_i x^i$ live in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: I've never heard the distinction between a graded ring and a cohomology graded ring.  Do you have a good reference for this distinction?  Because if this is indeed the case, it seems to be implicit in a lot of material.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon: If $\deg x =0$, then the graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the usual thing: it's the ordinary polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in dimension $0$ and $0$ elsewhere. For $\deg x > 0$, it's basically $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

Comment: The difference is between a nongraded ring and a graded ring; $H^*(X)$ is just an example of the latter. Some sources take a graded ring to be an ordinary ring $R$ with a degree map that inducing a direct sum $R = \bigoplus R_*$. That's not the case here; we have a series of cohomology groups $H^*$ and combine them via cup product into a graded ring. In the category of finite CW complexes, or even constructing characteristic classes from the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$, it's not an issue. For references, I really haven't found a good book on homological algebra.

Comment: I'm still confused on the definitive answer.  To clarify, is it that in the category of graded rings, $\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{n+1})$ with $x$ sitting in positive degree is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and that $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is not a graded ring if we interpret it as power series?  Why then do we use power series notation for Conner-Floyd classes?

Comment: The graded ring in cohomology attached to $X$ should be $\prod H^*(X)$, not $\bigoplus H^*(X)$, in order to commute with limits. In the category of graded rings, the graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $x$ (not the ring $\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}x^n$ of polynomials in $x$) and the limit $\mathbb{Z}[[x]] =  \lim \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$ coincide. As for the notation, I've seen such classes use either notation; my guess is that one is more familiar than the other, and the difference isn't relevant in the finite case or at the level at Hatcher.

Comment: So you're saying that it is also correct to write Chern classes as a power series ring?

Comment: In any case, I care about these for infinite complexes!  I want to understand MU characteristic classes and so forth.

Comment: Yes, although $c_*(\xi)$ vanishes above the rank of $\xi$. No problem, I care very much about infinite complexes too. :)